# C++: Using recursion to find an int in a List - When to return

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to move recursively through each Node in a List class to find if a certain integer exists in one of the Nodes in the list.

This is my header file:

```
class List
{
public:
    bool find(int d) const { return false; }
private:
    Node *head;

    bool findNode(const Node*, int) const;
};
```

Here is the code for two functions:

```
bool List::find(int d) const
{
    return findNode(head, d);
}

bool List::findNode(const Node* n, int d) const
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return false;
    else if (n->data == d)
        return true;
    else
        findNode(n->next, d);
}
```

Now here's my question: Did I doom myself by adding the `if (n == NULL)` statement in the `findNode` function so that it always returns false? I don't think I need to do that if I already have `return false` in the header file. Should I remove that line, and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (n == NULL) return false` is good, because it'll only happen when you've reached the end of the list and you should return false.

The first issue I see is that the line `findNode(n->next, d);` should be `return findNode(n->next, d);`

The second is that you need to remove the function body for `find()` from your header file. You can't define the function body twice.

Thus, the complete code is:

```
class List
{
public:
    bool find(int d) const;
private:
    Node *head;
    bool findNode(const Node*, int) const;
};

bool List::find(int d) const
{
    return findNode(head, d);
}

bool List::findNode(const Node* n, int d) const
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return false;
    else if (n->data == d)
        return true;
    else
        return findNode(n->next, d);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I HATE the header file, but it was given to me by the instructor and we are not allowed to change it (AWFUL coding standards if you ask me...). I wouldn't do that in the header file at all, but you get what you get I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need the null check as that's how you determine the end of list. I guess you are trying this as an exercise otherwise obviously you don't need recursion here at all.

Comment: Yeah, I normally wouldn't use recursion, as it's very expensive. This is for one of my classes.